# Problem with session variables using ColdFusion, Tomcat and Firefox

Tags: tomcat, firefox, coldfusion

Any help is appreciated.

When using cfimage to generate a captcha, we keep his value in a session variable.

After the user submits the form, we compare the value of the captcha that the user entered with the session variable value.

Like this:

Step one - User arrives the form with captcha.

Step two - Is created the variable SESSION.CAPTCHA_VALUE with the captcha value created by cfimage.

Step three - The user fill's in the form and submit it.

Step four - We compare the value of SESSION.CAPTCHA_VALUE with the value that the user entered.

We implemented this because of spam bot's.

The problem is in the value of SESSION.CAPTCHA_VALUE only in Firefox. After submission, the value of SESSION.CAPTCHA_VALUE  is always different of the created but the JSESSION.ID is kept.

We are using ColdFusion in Tomcat and Firefox 3.5.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the use J2EE Session variables checkbox checked in ColdFusion Administrator?

If not ColdFusion is using its own internal session variables (CFID and CFTOKEN)

If you are experiencing a problem on just one browser, the probably is perhaps due to some cookies that you have stored. Try this on another computer using the same browser version, if it works the problem is not the browser itself, but rather your browser environment (cookies, etc).